# Does php automaticly close the TCP connection after every request?

Tags: php, apache, sockets, tcp, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Apache 2.4/PHP 5.6.13 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have an API connector which make 1 call per second per user to read a messaging queue.

I am using `setInterval(...., 1000)` to make an ajax request to a handler which does the actual API call.

The handler makes `cURL` calls to the API service to read the messaging queue.

This works fine for 2 users but now I have 10 users using the system which mean more API calls being sent from my server.

Many users "using the API caller or not" have been facing a timeout error. When I look at the php logs I see this fatal error

```
[14-Aug-2015 16:37:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
```

I did a research on this issue and found out that it is not really a SQL error but rather a windows error. [It is explained here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full.aspx)

It seems to me that I will need to edit the Windows Registry to correct the issue as it is [explained here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196271) but I don't like touching windows registry specially on a production server.

My question is does PHP keep ths TCP connection open or does it close it after every request?

I have 10 users using the "API caller" and about 200 that were not. This is only addition was 10 users/10 API calls per second.

Assuming that PHP/cURL automaticly close the TCP connection, then how could I be reaching and 5000 connection from only 10 people using the API?

Comment: which tcp connection? the one that caused PHP to start up (e.g. http request), or whatever tcp connection the DB is using?

Comment: @MarcB I am not sure if I understand the question. but  in the logs this error is thrown from the class the makes PDO connection to the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in your application's architecture. Ajax polling is not scalable.

*Short polling* (what you do) is not scalable, because it just floods the server with requests. You have one request per second and per user. This gives already 10 requests per second for 10 users. You set up a DoS attack against your server!

*Long polling* (also called comet) means that your server does not immediately respond to the request, but waits until there's a message to send or until a timeout is reached. This is better, because you have lesser requests now. But it is still not scalable because on the server you will continue to hammer onto the database.

*Websockets* is what you are looking for. Your browser connects to the websocket server, and keeps the connection forever. It is a two way communication channel that is always available to both sides. There are two more things to know :

- you need another server for websockets, Apache can't do it.
- on the server side you need an event system. Hammering on the database is just not a solution.

Look into `ratchet` as a php based websocket deamon, and into Autobahn.js for the client side.

**Edit:** `Ratchet` is unfortunately no longer maintained. I switched to node.js.

Comment: Thank you. I like your answer. as I attempted to be a server-sent-event which did not work well for me. I tried to build a Web-sockets using node.js which I could not figure out how to do. any Idea on how to create a websocket? also, will the websocket need to be on a separate server not on the one that is running php?

Comment: I have ratchet (socketo.me) with 0MQ (zeromq.org) in a production environment and it works great. Just follow their tutorial. It looks scary in the beginning, but it gets easy as you follow it. And when you're done with the the tutorial, you have 3/4 of your final code.

Answer (score 1):

PHP database connections use the PDO base class. By default they are closed each time a request is finished (the PHP script finishes). You can find out more information related to this here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php.

You can force your database connection to be persistent which is normally beneficial if you are going to reuse the database connection often.

Apache is (im assuming) like other servers. It is constantly listening on a given port for incoming connections. It establishes that connection reads the request sends out a response and then closes the connection.

Your error is caused by taking up to many connections (the OS will only allow so many) OR overflowing the buffer for the connection. Both of these can be inferred from your error message.

Comment: the issue here is not with databases but with the TCP connections to the API

Comment: What do you mean TCP connections to the API? Which API? What TCP connections?

Comment: in my question I explained that I am making a call to an API every 1 second which seems to be causing the problem. something is using up TCP connection which is running me into max connections

Comment: If the TCP connection auto closes then how could I be reaching and 5000 connection which seems to be the issue?

Comment: What API? On your webserver? I believe you are simply sending a http GET request to your server every 1 second in order to receive some information correct? The error here lies with your webserver not handling database connections properly. Thus forcing the OS to throw an error because you are overloading the OS with to many connections.